# Material UI Checkbox not toggling on and off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im not exactly sure what's going on because in the Material UI docs, it seems pretty simple, but I can't get my checkbox to toggle either on or off after I create the component.

```
const createCheckBox = (row, checkBoxStatus, changeStatus) => {
    let text = "";
    if (row.values.map((value, index) => {
        text += value.title
    }))
        if (text) {
            return (
                <Checkbox checked />
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <Checkbox checked={false} disabled />
            )
        }
}
```

I'm creating new checkboxes for a set number of rows. Each row has a text value, and there's text, I want to be able to toggle the row's checkbox on or off, but if there's no text, I want the box to be disabled and not checked marked.

I weird thing is, that if I remove the `checked` from the true portion of the code, i can toggle the checkbox but can't when I set it.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so add them here. Try checking the length of the text in your if statement. `if(text.length > 0)`

Comment: @SebastianGbudje no errors. I have the text hard coded at the moment so I know what the values are. There no null values or empty strings in ```text```

Comment: `checked` is a truthy prop, so the checkbox is "stuck" checked, and `checked={false}` makes it "stuck" unchecked. Nothing is toggleable. Why are you rendering 2 checkboxes and conditionally rendering one or the other?

Comment: @DrewReese That makes sense. Basically Im only trying to render 1 checkbox, but they need to be render based on if text has a value or not.

Comment: So `checked={!!text}`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but after I ask these questions I'm usually able to figure it out myself after asking them.

Here's what I got.

I set the true condition to this

```
<Checkbox defaultChecked />
```

But then it gave me this error.

> MUI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled SwitchBase.

Only for it to give
so I changed the checkbox to this.

```
<Checkbox value={row.name + "_checkbox"} defaultChecked />
```

Then it gave me some error about not having a key so I added a key to the checkbox

```
<Checkbox key={row.name + "_checkbox_key"} value={row.name + "_checkbox"} defaultChecked />
```

Now everything works the way I wanted it to work.